# How to create separate shop pages in woocommerce for each product category

Tags: plugins

How to create separate shop pages in woocommerce for each product category i.e. computers, cameras, cellphones, software, books, etc.

Answer (score 7):

example woocommerce structure:

```
shop
 |
 |-category1
 | |
 | |-product1
 | |-product2
 |
 |-category2
   |
   |-subcategory2.1
   | |
   | |-product3
   | |-product4
   |
   |-subcategory2.2
     |
     |-product5
     |-product6
```

each (sub)category has it's own archive page. instead of showing the main shop page in your menu, just put those pages seperately into the menu, under: 
`→ design → menu`. besides that you can configure your woocommerce under: `→ woocommerce → settings`.

---

edit - step-by-step:

1. go to: → Appearance → Menus;
2. remove »Shop« from menu;
3. at the top of your window click on »Screen Options«;
4. add a checkmark on »Product Categories«;
5. now you can add the »Product Categories« to your menu;

Comment: Thanks @ngsonst for your quick response. I am not kind of a techie guy and I'm not sure how to do it. It is highly appreciated if you can provide me a step-by step guide. Thanks.